# chat room moderators

Tags: discussion, chat

I will like to know who is the moderator of python chat room that can be found here...

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python

The reason I am asking is that one of the user Ffisegydd told me not to ask SO questions in the chat.
He also asked another user not to answer my question. [Here is what I was told](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python):

> @shantanuo in the future, please don't bring your new questions here.
>
> It's not appropriate and against the chat room rules.
>
> Also if you are going to try and get your answer, you should at least do everyone else on SO the courtesy of editing your question to include any extra information you give here.
>
> @Swordy nice answer ;) it does exactly what he asks for. Don't add the additional pieces until he's edited the question though.
>
> Otherwise you're not actually answering the question, if you see what I mean.
>
> I'd also suggest not even sharing the solution with him here in chat, as that'll force him to do the decent thing and update his own question.

I will like to know the link to "Chat room rules".
I will also like to know who is the python chat room moderator.

Comment: Do we really need a rule about this? It's just common sense. We have a programming Q&A site, post your programming questions there.

Answer (score 18):

I think Martijn has explained things properly but I'll explain my point of view anyway.

shantanuo posted a question the main SO website and then came into chat to discuss it. As Martijn has stated, this is against our chatroom rules (which are clearly linked to in the chat description). I asked shantanuo to not break our rules.

Before I came on, however, he had been speaking to another member of the room. shantanuo had given extra detail for his question and had actually modified what needed to be done **without editing his original question on the main site.** This means that people who read the chat (and possibly answered the question) would have more detail and would, in effect, be answering a different question to the one actually written on the main site. *This could lead to confusion for other users in the future, the question and the answer would not match.*

I suggested to Swordy, the user who was looking to answer the question, that he wait for the question to be updated, for the reasons I've stated above.

shantanuo: At no point did you reply to any of the messages that I sent to you, speaking about the rules. You did not ask for a link to the rules. You were silent until you posted this meta post. In the future, if you are unsure about something, then please ask for clarification, I am one of the Room Owners and part of what we volunteer to do is help people of the community.

Answer (score 17):

The community in a chat room can set rules for how we like to conduct ourselves in the room and how we expect others to behave. The Python chat room is very open about their rules, and the room description (located at the top right of the chat user interface) provides you with a link:

> Please do other members the courtesy of reading http://sopython.com/pages/chatroom

Those rules include:

> #### Posting Question/Answer Links
>
> - Do not link your recently posted questions in the room. The main site is the dedicated space for posting questions, and having them answered.
> - If you have posted a question on the main site and a significant amount of time has passed without receiving a satisfying answer, then you can discuss your question in the room.

All Ffisegydd did was remind you of those rules.

Ffisegydd is one of the chat room owners, as am I. You can see all users with that role listed on the [room information page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python). We are *not* moderators, we are merely the users that administrate the room.

The reason we set this rule is because those that can answer these questions are *already watching the questions page*, your recent question would already have been looked at. As such there is no need to clutter up the chat room with the same link again.

The chatroom holds meetings once every two months or so; you are welcome to come and discuss our rules at one of those. Watch the events listing in the room (we had one very recently so it'll be a while until the next one).

As for the comments towards Swordy; you clarified your question in the chatroom; Swordy answered the *clarified question* in the chatroom. To be able to post that as an answer on Stack Overflow, the question post would have to be updated to include the extra information you gave, otherwise Swordy's answer would look incorrect to future visitors of the question.